# Java MQ Client 7.5 with JDK 1.8 Topic subscribtion issue[JMSWMQ0026]

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to a Topic in MQ Server 7.1 in java 1.6 . My Java client is running in jdk 1.8 with MQ Client 7.5 libraries. I am getting a error

```
TopicHandler
The Q name is :/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/*
SSL is enabled for Topic connection
MQ MNRG FLAG: false
Connection establisted with topic manager
Got topic manager session
Got topic object
Starting the session
Starting subscriber...
with topic:topic:///WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/* and name:/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/*
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic '/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/*' using MQSUB.
There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:521)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:129)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:871)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:139)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.<init>(WMQMessageConsumer.java:296)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(WMQSession.java:825)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:980)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:1019)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createDurableSubscriber(MQSession.java:531)
        at MQTopicHandler.startSubscriber(MQTopicHandler.java:248)
        at MQTopicHandler.<init>(MQTopicHandler.java:176)
        at MQTopicHandler.main(MQTopicHandler.java:396)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
        ... 11 more
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic '/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/*' using MQSUB.
There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:521)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:129)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:871)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:139)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.<init>(WMQMessageConsumer.java:296)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(WMQSession.java:825)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:980)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:1019)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createDurableSubscriber(MQSession.java:531)
        at MQTopicHandler.startSubscriber(MQTopicHandler.java:248)
        at MQTopicHandler.<init>(MQTopicHandler.java:176)
        at MQTopicHandler.main(MQTopicHandler.java:396)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
        ... 11 more
Exception Msg: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic '/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/*' using MQSUB.
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic '/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/*' using MQSUB.
There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information.
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:521)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:129)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:871)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:139)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.<init>(WMQMessageConsumer.java:296)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(WMQSession.java:825)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:980)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:1019)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createDurableSubscriber(MQSession.java:531)
        at MQTopicHandler.startSubscriber(MQTopicHandler.java:248)
        at MQTopicHandler.<init>(MQTopicHandler.java:176)
        at MQTopicHandler.main(MQTopicHandler.java:396)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
        ... 11 more
JMS Error code: JMSWMQ0026
JMS Explanation: There may have been a problem creating the subscription due to it being used by another message consumer.
JMS Explanation: Make sure any message consumers using this subscription are closed before trying to create a new subscription under the same name. Please see the linked exception for more information.
Exception Msg: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.checkJmqiCallSuccess(WMQMessageConsumer.java:129)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQConsumerShadow.java:871)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSyncConsumerShadow.initialize(WMQSyncConsumerShadow.java:139)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQMessageConsumer.<init>(WMQMessageConsumer.java:296)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.createDurableSubscriber(WMQSession.java:825)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:980)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.createDurableSubscriber(JmsSessionImpl.java:1019)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.createDurableSubscriber(MQSession.java:531)
        at MQTopicHandler.startSubscriber(MQTopicHandler.java:248)
        at MQTopicHandler.<init>(MQTopicHandler.java:176)
        at MQTopicHandler.main(MQTopicHandler.java:396)
WMQ Completion code: 2
WMQ Reason code: 2035
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: JMSWMQ0026: Failed to subscribe to topic '/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/*' using MQSUB.
        at MQTopicHandler.<init>(MQTopicHandler.java:230)
        at MQTopicHandler.main(MQTopicHandler.java:396)
```

Checked the MQ Server there are no subscribers with my Client ID and also refreshed the MQ Server.

Comment: can you post your code for the JMS Subscriber ?

Comment: Can you post the linked exception? We will need the MQ reason code to understand the cause for the MQSUB call failure.

Comment: updated with linked exception

Comment: The exception clearly says that this is caused by some authorization issue: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED'). You should check what user id you are forwarding to MQ and that that user is authorized to access the topic.

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR 2016-09-06 10:22:52,974 startSubscriber: Exception occurred:
>   com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ0026:
>   Failed to subscribe to topic '/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/*/*'
>   using MQSUB.

Shouldn't that be '/WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/#' ?  '#' (number sign) is the wild card for Pub/Sub.

Comment: Tried with /WFADO/INSTALL/SHARED_SERVICES/#/# still the same error

Comment: Why are you putting 2 #'s ?